# cusparse sparse-dense multiplication x4 larger cost over x100 more time

Tags: cuda

Using cusparse, I first tried a sparse-dense multiplication with the following sizes:

```
C1 [8692 x 8692] = A1 [8692 x 7000 sparse] x B1 [7000 x 8692]
```

It takes only 0.3 seconds. Then I did another one with the following sizes:

```
C2 [8820 x 8820] = A2 [8820 x 32000 sparse] x B2 [32000 x 8820]
```

The time it takes varies depending on what's in the sparse matrix, but it ranges from 30 seconds to 90 seconds. Is there anything I can do to accelerate it? I can chop the matrices in different ways if that can reduce the running time, but I'm not sure what the performance issues are here.

The sparse matrices A1 and A2 are stored in CSR formats and they do have a bad sparsity pattern, but they are equally bad. The two figures below show where the non-zero elements are in A1 and A2 respectively. The non-zero elements per column in both cases are controlled to be fixed at 127.

[image: Non-zero elements in A1]

[image: Non-zero elements in A2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sparsity pattern of the matrix, you should split the matrix A1 in 2 parts with a matrix  A11  containing about the first 8000 rows and A12 the remaining rows and use the csrmv twice. This way, cusparse will choose a better heuristic for the numbers of threads per row.

You should also consider using the new version in CUSPARSE 6.0  csrmv2 with the transpose case . You would need to transpose B first ( using cublasgeam ) and do :

C = A1 * (B')'

The transpose case is much better because the access to B are all coalesced.

Another option would be to densify A1 ( using cusparsecsr2dense ) and use cublas

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that. Do you mean csrmm2 in cusparse 6? And is it always better to have matrix B transposed?